# Fancybox reusable code

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I have multiple fancy box on one page but I want to create only one method to mange all these fancy box.Please help thanks in advance

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
            $("a[rel=example_group]").fancybox({
                'transitionIn'      : 'none',
                'transitionOut'     : 'none',
                'titlePosition'     : 'over',
                'titleFormat'       : function(title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {
                    return '<span id="fancybox-title-over">Image ' + (currentIndex + 1) + ' / ' + currentArray.length + (title.length ? ' &nbsp; ' + title : '') + '</span>';
                }
            });


            $("a[rel=example_group_crm]").fancybox({
                'transitionIn'      : 'none',
                'transitionOut'     : 'none',
                'titlePosition'     : 'over',
                'titleFormat'       : function(title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {
                    return '<span id="fancybox-title-over">Image ' + (currentIndex + 1) + ' / ' + currentArray.length + (title.length ? ' &nbsp; ' + title : '') + '</span>';
                }
            });

            $("a[rel=example_group_human]").fancybox({
                'transitionIn'      : 'none',
                'transitionOut'     : 'none',
                'titlePosition'     : 'over',
                'titleFormat'       : function(title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {
                    return '<span id="fancybox-title-over">Image ' + (currentIndex + 1) + ' / ' + currentArray.length + (title.length ? ' &nbsp; ' + title : '') + '</span>';
                }
            });

 });
```

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous ways to shorten your code, you could, for example add some class to these links and use that class as selector. Or you could use some regexp to select links having `rel` attribute like this:

```
$("a[rel^=example_group]").fancybox({
   // your parameters
});
```

Or you can create your own method that receives selector as a parameter and then applies fancyBox.